# Create .jsonl files from .csv

Tags: csv, automl

I want to use `AutoML`, specifically the `Entity extraction`, however, I'm asked to upload a .jsonl file. 
I don't know that a .jsonl file is nor how to create it. I only have a .csv file.
So, how can I create a .jsonl file from a .csv file? And if that is not possible, how can I create a .jsonl file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is JSONlines http://jsonlines.org/

And you can use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller). In example if your input CSV is

```
fieldOne,FieldTwo
1,lorem
2,ipsum
```

you can run

```
mlr --c2j cat input_01.csv >output.json
```

to have

```
{ "fieldOne": 1, "FieldTwo": "lorem" }
{ "fieldOne": 2, "FieldTwo": "ipsum" }
```

This output is a JSON Lines (one valid JSON object, for each row). If you want a JSON you must add the `--jlistwrap` flag.

```
mlr --c2j --jlistwrap cat input.csv
```

to have

```json
[
{ "fieldOne": 1, "FieldTwo": "lorem" }
,{ "fieldOne": 2, "FieldTwo": "ipsum" }
]
```